# Copy files in a folder to another folder but only specified files, *.rar

Tags: batch-file, copy, paste

I need code that works same way as the move function:

```
move "rar\*.rar" %rarfolder"
```

The folder `rar` will contain more than only the *.rar files, and I don't want to move the files, I want to copy the files. How can I do that?

Comment: batch, also tagged in batch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `set rarfolder=_YourDestinationFolder_`, try:

```
 robocopy rar %rarfolder% *.rar
```

I prefer using [Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy), because it allows you to do more than the normal copy / move commands.